# Where does one get the info to run software off of the software center download site?

Tags: programming, irc

Like for instance I see a lot of Qt and C++ programs but where is the background info, like getting on IRC and using the kde gui?  Is there info in the archives on how to program or am I going to have to get a book?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are searching for source code of the app, you can obtain it using

apt-get source

Eg

apt-get source vlc